# How do I Upload an audio track to my game using HTML and JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, soundcloud

I am developing a game as part of a project I'm working on for my course. I need to upload a single MP3 track onto my game when the page loads however the below I thought would work isnt?

Any ideas?

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="kanye.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

My game is a Kanye game and I want one of his tracks to play when you upload the game.